# Parse and define a literal

Tags: algorithm, stored-procedures, scheme, racket

I have a literal defined by this method:

```
  (define right-hand-rule-prg
      '(
        (procedure start
          ( turn-right
            (if wall?
               ( turn-left
                 (if wall?
                     (turn-left
                         (if wall?
                            turn-left
                            step
                         )
                     )
                     step
                  )
               )
               step  
            )
            put-mark
            start
          )
        )   
        (procedure turn-right (turn-left turn-left turn-left turn-left turn-left))
      )
    )
```

And I have to parse and define procedure `start` and `turn-right`.

I managed to get procedure by the name using this method:

```
(define (get-procedure procedure program)
  (if (null? program)
      '(procedure-not-found)
      (if (eq? procedure (cadar program))
          (caddar program)
          (get-procedure procedure (cdr program))
          )
      )  
  )
```

So after calling I get:

```
(get-procedure 'turn-right right-hand-rule-prg)
'(turn-left turn-left turn-left turn-left turn-left)
```

But somehow I have to manage to find all procedure name and define this procedure like this:

```
(define (name-of-procedure) (get-procedure name-of-procedure-program))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This would involve creating identifiers by using macros that manipulate the syntax of your program or, worse, use `eval` if you can't know the procedure list in advance. This is definitely not a beginner's level, and even then I believe it should be avoided here. Do you really want/need to do this? Is this an assignment? To me, it seems that `get-procedure` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the motivation/context, what you're trying to do here. But what you've sketched out seems to be "cutting against the grain".

In Scheme and Racket, functions are first-class objects -- you can put them in lists, pass them around, and so on. It would be simpler, and "cutting *with* the grain" to flip it around: Define the functions as usual, and make `right-hand-rule-prg` a `list` of the functions.

```
(define (turn-left)
  ...)

(define (turn-right)
  ...)

(define (start)
  ...)

(define right-hand-rule-prg
  (list start turn-right))
```

And to execute `right-hand-rule-prg` you can do something like the following to run the procedures in the list:

```
(for ([f (in-list right-hand-rule-prg)])
  (f))
```

Note that something like `right-hand-rule-prg` is a `list` that can be built or modified at runtime. So you could let e.g. a user modify this, or read it from a file. However the building blocks -- the primitives like `start` and `turn-right` -- are normally defined functions.

If you *truly* need to define primitives at run time, you *could* use `eval` on a user-supplied s-expression. But it's the least desirable choice. You should try to avoid `eval`.  If you want the user to contribute arbitrary Racket functions at runtime, it would be better to use something like `dynamic-require`. Or even better, invert the control -- your code is a library for the user's program (rather than your code utilizing the user's code at runtime).